# Loading indicator appears but does not move in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { BiLeftArrow, BiRightArrow } from "react-icons/bi";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

import {
  fetchMovies,
  handleCurrentPage,
  handleStatus,
} from "../../feautures/movies/moviesSlice";
import Card from "../Card/Card";
import Slider from "../UI/Slider/Slider";
import Navigation from "../Navigations/Navigation";

import "./MoviesList.scss";
import requests from "../../requests";
import LoadingIndicator from "../UI/LoadingIndicator/LoadingIndicator";

const MoviesList = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // Handle movies states
  const moviesStatus = useSelector((state) => state.movies.status);
  const moviesState = useSelector((state) => state.movies.movies);
  const moviesError = useSelector((state) => state.movies.error);
  const moviesHeading = useSelector((state) => state.movies.moviesHeading); // It's for pagination
  const moviesCurrentPage = useSelector((state) => state.movies.currentPage);

  let history = useHistory();

  // Handle header input
  const inputValue = useSelector((state) => state.movies.inputValue);

  // Movies according input values
  const filteredMovie = moviesState.filter((movie) =>
    movie.original_title.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue)
  );

  // Handle page number
  const handlePageNumber = (nexPage) => {
    dispatch(handleStatus("idle"));
    dispatch(
      handleCurrentPage(Math.max(1, Math.min(moviesCurrentPage + nexPage, 10)))
    );
  };

  // Handle pagination
  useEffect(() => {
    if (moviesStatus === "idle") {
      if (moviesHeading === "POPULAR") {
        dispatch(fetchMovies(requests.fetchPopular(moviesCurrentPage)));
      } else if (moviesHeading === "NOW PLAYING") {
        dispatch(fetchMovies(requests.fetchNowPlaying(moviesCurrentPage)));
      } else if (moviesHeading === "UP COMING") {
        dispatch(fetchMovies(requests.fetchUpComing(moviesCurrentPage)));
      }
    }
  }, [moviesCurrentPage, dispatch, moviesHeading, moviesStatus]);

  let content;

  if (moviesStatus === "loading") {
  } else if (moviesStatus === "succeeded") {
    content = (
      <div className="movies__container">
        <BiLeftArrow
          className="movies__arrow movies__arrow--left"
          onClick={() => {
            handlePageNumber(-1);
            history.push(
              `/page/${(() =>
                Math.max(1, Math.min(moviesCurrentPage - 1, 10)))()}`
            );
          }}
        />
        {filteredMovie.map((movie) => {
          return <Card movie={movie} key={movie.id} />;
        })}
        <BiRightArrow
          className="movies__arrow movies__arrow--right"
          onClick={() => {
            handlePageNumber(1);
            history.push(
              `/page/${(() =>
                Math.max(1, Math.min(moviesCurrentPage + 1, 10)))()}`
            );
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  } else if (moviesStatus === "failed") {
    content = <div>{moviesError}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="movies">
      <Slider />
      <Navigation />
      {moviesStatus === "loading" ? <LoadingIndicator /> : content}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MoviesList;
```

LoadingIndicator.jsx

```
import "./LoadingIndicator.scss"

const LoadingIndicator = () => {
  return (
    <div className="loading">
      <div className="loading__circle"></div>
      <div className="loading__circle"></div>
      <div className="loading__circle"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoadingIndicator;
```

LoadingIndicator.scss

```
.loading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-self: center;
  
  width: 480px;
  &__circle {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%,
      rgba(9, 9, 121, 1) 35%,
      rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%
    );
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    transform: translateX(0);
    z-index: 2;
    &:nth-child(1) {
      animation: move-1 2s infinite;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      animation: move-3 2s infinite;
    }
  }
}
@keyframes move-1 {
  0% {
    z-index: 3;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  25% {
    z-index: 3;
    transform: translateX(80px);
  }
  50% {
    z-index: 3;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  50.1% {
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  75% {
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateX(80px);
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes move-3 {
  0% {
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  25% {
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateX(-80px);
  }
  50% {
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  50.1% {
    z-index: 3;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  75% {
    z-index: 3;
    transform: translateX(-80px);
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 3;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

Hi all.I try to show `<LoadingIndicator />` component when `moviesStatus === "loading"` until `moviesStatus === "succeeded"` but issue is `<LoadingIndicator />` component appears but doesnt move as you can see in demo(three big blue balls).I literally do the same things in this documentation(https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reduxjs/redux-essentials-example-app/tree/checkpoint-3-postRequests/?from-embed=&file=/src/features/posts/PostsList.js) but doesnt work.I haven't been able to solve the problem for days.

demo : https://hope-movie.web.app/page/1
repo : https://github.com/UmutPalabiyik/hope-movie-app

Comment: Can you provide code+css of <LoadingIndicator /> ?

Comment: I added but i don't think it's about that because  <LoadingIndicator /> component work properly in somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got response from server very quickly, so you can not see LoadingIndicator. To see LoadingIndicator you can make getting response slower manually. You can update you `fetchMovies` function like this:

```js
export const fetchMovies = createAsyncThunk("movies/fetch", async (arg) => {
  return await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      console.log("url: ", arg);
      const response = await axios.get(arg);
      resolve(response.data.results);
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```